# plpgsql trigger - Passing a dynamic set of ids to an insert query (v9.6)

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

At a fundamental level this is what I want to accomplish.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION transform404activities() RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
DECLARE
    get404json text;

BEGIN
    get404json := 'insert into public.events_404_normalized(event_name) select json_data->>''event_name'' from public.event_404 WHERE id IN(select id from public.event_404 WHERE created_at < (select now()) AND processed is NULL)';
    EXECUTE format(get404json);
    RETURN NEW;
END
$$;
```

This works but it's limited since I want to do extra steps with the id's in the WHERE IN select statement so I'm wanting to make the set/array a variable.

I started out with this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION transform404activities() RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
DECLARE
    get404ids text;
    result404ids int ARRAY;
    get404json text;
    mark404processed text;

BEGIN
    get404ids := 'select id from public.event_404 WHERE created_at < (select now()) AND processed is NULL';
    EXECUTE format(get404ids) INTO result404ids;
    get404json := 'insert into public.events_404_normalized(event_name) select json_data->>''event_name'' from public.event_404 WHERE id = ANY (result404ids)';
    EXECUTE format(get404json);
    mark404processed := 'UPDATE public.event_404 SET processed = TRUE WHERE id IN(result404ids)';
    RETURN NEW;
END
$$;
```

When the trigger is run the result gives an error of:

```
ERROR:  malformed array literal: "51"
DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function transform404activities() line 10 at EXECUTE
```

Which makes sense because it's not an array.

```
select id from public.event_404 WHERE created_at < (select now()) AND processed is NULL;
 id 
----
 51
 52
 53
 50
(4 rows)
```

However the moment I introduce array_agg the trigger wants to use the variable literally and not the contents of the array.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION transform404activities() RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
DECLARE
    get404ids text;
    result404ids int ARRAY;
    get404json text;
    mark404processed text;

BEGIN
    get404ids := 'select array_agg(id) from public.event_404 WHERE created_at < (select now()) AND processed is NULL';
    EXECUTE format(get404ids) INTO result404ids;
    get404json := 'insert into public.events_404_normalized(event_name) select json_data->>''event_name'' from public.event_404 WHERE id = ANY (result404ids)';
    EXECUTE format(get404json);
    mark404processed := 'UPDATE public.event_404 SET processed = TRUE WHERE id IN(result404ids)';
    RETURN NEW;
END
$$;
```

The trigger results in this error:

```
ERROR:  column "result404ids" does not exist
LINE 1: ...event_name' from public.event_404 WHERE id = ANY (result404i...
                                                             ^
QUERY:  insert into public.events_404_normalized(event_name) select json_data->>'event_name' from public.event_404 WHERE id = ANY (result404ids)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function transform404activities() line 12 at EXECUTE
```

I'm expecting my variable to contain the following:

```
select array_agg(id) from public.event_404 WHERE created_at < (select now()) AND processed is NULL;
   array_agg   
---------------
 {51,52,53,50}
```

I seem to be missing something basic but everything I've attempted to do results in the same "ERROR:  column "result404ids" does not exist" error.

**UPDATE**
I rewrote my trigger and removed a lot of the cruft.  This works as expected:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION transform404activities() RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
DECLARE
    result404ids text;

BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'select array_agg(id) from public.event_404 WHERE created_at < (select now()) AND processed is NULL' INTO result404ids;
    EXECUTE 'insert into public.events_404_normalized(event_name,language) select json_data->>''event_name'',json_data->>''language'' from event_404 WHERE id = ANY( '|| quote_literal(result404ids) ||')';
    RETURN NEW;
END
$$;
```

**UPDATE 2**

Using Klin's suggestion my final result is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION transform404activities() RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
DECLARE
    get404ids text;
    result404ids int ARRAY;
    get404json text;

BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'select array_agg(id) from public.event_404 WHERE created_at < (select now()) AND processed is NULL' INTO result404ids;
    get404json := 'insert into public.events_404_normalized(event_name,language) select json_data->>''event_name'', json_data->>''language'' from public.event_404 WHERE id = ANY ($1)';
    execute get404json using result404ids;
    RETURN NEW;
END
$$;
```

Comment: In this case, you don't need dynamic SQL. Remove it. It has significant overhead - more in trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `execute ... using ...`:

```
...
get404json := 'insert into public.events_404_normalized(event_name) select json_data->>''event_name'' from public.event_404 WHERE id = ANY ($1)';
execute get404json using result404ids;
...
```

See [Executing Dynamic Commands](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) in the documentation.

Comment: I'll try your way as well, perhaps I can get rid of the quote_literal bit.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion I've updated my question with working code.